# Store gorm logs in a file

Tags: go, go-gorm

I would like to store the `gorm` logs in a file. However I could not find any example or documentation for that. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4):

You may pass a [`*gorm.Config`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#Config) value to [`gorm.Open()`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#Open) (it implements [`gorm.Option`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#Option)) where you may specify a custom logger.

You may create your logger using [`logger.New()`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm@v1.21.16/logger#New) which allows you to pass a [`logger.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm@v1.21.16/logger#Writer) that is responsible to log messages, which may log to a file for example.

Note that `logger.Writer` is an interface that is implemented by the standard library's [`log.Logger`](https://pkg.go.dev/log#Logger). You may create a standard library's logger directed to a file using [`log.New()`](https://pkg.go.dev/log#New).

Putting the pieces together:

```
file, err := os.Create("gorm-log.txt")
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    panic(err)
}
// Make sure file is closed before your app shuts down.

fileLogger := logger.New(file, "", log.LstdFlags)

db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
  Logger: fileLogger,
})
```

The above example will replace the default logger with `fileLogger` which will log only to file. If you want to log both to your console (standard output) and to a file, you may use [`io.MultiWriter()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter) to create an [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) that writes to both the standard output and to a file:

```
file, err := os.Create("gorm-log.txt")
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    panic(err)
}
// Make sure file is closed before your app shuts down.

multiOutput := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, file)

multiLogger := logger.New(multiOutput, "", log.LstdFlags)

db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
  Logger: multiLogger,
})
```

Read more about gorm logging here: https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html